# Get values from URL in Java

Tags: java, android-studio, url

I want to get "BusinessId" from this URL in Java:  https://example.com/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.cp&hl=es&apn=com.picker.cp&st=Share+this+app&utm_source=AndroidApp?businessId=5d8648b561abf51ff7a6c189

What can i do? 
I need some help, please :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `String#replaceAll` for a one-line solution:

```
String url = "https://example.com/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.cp&hl=es&apn=com.picker.cp&st=Share+this+app&utm_source=AndroidApp?businessId=5d8648b561abf51ff7a6c189";
String businessId = url.replaceAll(".*[&?]businessId=([^=?&]+)\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println(businessId);
```

This prints:

```
5d8648b561abf51ff7a6c189
```

Actually Apache has a number of libraries that can make handling your requirement much easier.  On Android, the following might work:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String linkParam = uri.getQueryParameter("link");
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(linkParam);
String businessId = uri2.getQueryParameter("businessId");
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed android tag in your question. You can parse the Url string to Uri and then you can get query param.

```
String myUrl = "https://example.com/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.cp&hl=es&apn=com.picker.cp&st=Share+this+app&utm_source=AndroidApp?businessId=5d8648b561abf51ff7a6c189";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(myUrl);
String businessId = uri.getQueryParameter("businessId");
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  The `businessId` query parameter is part of another URL which itself is part of the actual URL.

Comment: Haven't tried it but I assume it should work. Kindly share any gap you notice. And If it doesn't then it may be easy to do a regex match to find expected value. What do you think?